# @Html.BeginForm does not redirect to assigned ActionName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SerialNumber", "Test", FormMethod.Get))
   {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-8 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="color-name">
                            Serial Number <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 input-group">
                            @Html.TextBox("serial_number", null, new { @id = "txtSearch", @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12", type = "text", required = "required" })
                            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
 }
```

I'm trying to pass TextBox "serial_number" value to "SerialNumber" ActionResult of Test Controller. But the value is only passing to "AddSerialNumber" ActionResult of Test Controller. I've tried my best but I couldn't find the solution. Please Help.

[Please See the Application ScreenShot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDgl7.png)

```
    public ActionResult AddSerialNumber()
    {
        return View(db.sales.ToList()); 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SerialNumber(int serial_number)
    {
         ...
         return View();
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming you have decorated `SerialNumber` with the `[HttpPost]` attribute

Comment: Have you got something strange at your ruteMap ?

Comment: Is there some other code (...) in ActionResult SerialNumber ?

Comment: Your form has an FormMethod.Get?!!

Comment: Yes there are other code to add data from that serial_number. @RickL

Comment: OK, but I was looking for something that might Redirect to AddSerialNumber, like if (!ModelState.IsValid)

Comment: Yes, its FormMethod.Get i'hv tried Post method also but it didnt work. But from Get method if i change AddSerialNumber to SerialNumber in url, the rest of code is working properly by getting that serial_number from TextBox. @Wheels73

Comment: @AnupShrestha - First of all, I'd recommend use a strongly typed model for your view. I'd also then use Html.TextBoxFor to bind the values entered to the model. Change your form method to a Post, change the signature of your controller method to accept the model , then decorate the method with HttpPost and all should be well

Comment: There nothing which might Redirect to AddSerialNumber, There is code to add data to the table by getting the SerialNumber from TextBox. The code is working fine if i replace AddSerialNumber to SerialNumber in url manually after passing value in TextField. @RickL

Comment: @Anup Shrestha is this form nested within another form that goes to AddSerialNumber ?

Comment: @RickL NO, there is only one form. This form is in AddSerialNumber View.

Comment: @RickL Thank You, sir. I found the Error.  You were right I was using html.BeginForm inside HTML form. Thanks Alot. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try posting data with `formmethod POST` and with annotation `POST` for `controller action` method.

and  give id as `serial_number`  for text box you have given as  `txtSearch`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SerialNumber", "Test", FormMethod.POST))
       {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="color-name">
                                Serial Number <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 input-group">
                                @Html.TextBox("serial_number", null, new { @id = "serial_number", @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12", type = "text", required = "required" })
                                <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
     }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SerialNumber(string serial_number)
    {
         ...
         return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SerialNumber(string serial_number)
{
     ...
     return View();
}
```

You have to use string variable for get value of textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not the case here.

Comment: with HttpGet you cant post data to controller action i think.

Answer (score 0):

try the below approach.

Create your view model and perhaps a class to hold sales.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Sale
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller, have the following actions.

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult AddSerialNumber()
  {
      var myModel = new ViewModel();
      myModel.Sales = db.sales.ToList();

      return View(myModel);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult SerialNumber(ViewModel modelPosted)
  {
        //Do stuf with model
        return View();
  }
```

Then construct your  view from the model and change to a Post directive.

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SerialNumber", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-8 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="color-name">
                    Serial Number <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.SerialNumber, new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12", required = "required" })
                    <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        }
```

This will then post to your controller. I've had a simple set up locally and it works.

Hope that helps.

Ps. have to go.. so good luck